# Куда сохраняются файлы при загрузке через форму?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser

**Код:**

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    var txt = "";
    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
                var file = x.files[i];
                if ('name' in file) {
                    txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
                }
                if ('size' in file) {
                    txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (x.value == "") {
            txt += "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
            txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value; // If the browser does not support the files property, it will return the path of the selected file instead. 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Use the Control or the Shift key to select multiple files.</p>
```

[image: загрузка файла javascript]

Comment: Используйте отступ в четыре пробела или клавишу `{}` для оформления кода.

Comment: Что значит "куда сохраняется"? "При загрузке" куда?

Comment: @Gikas то и значит, куда сохраняется файл в браузере когда ты его прокидываешь через форму, что не понятного?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: вопрос снят. вот файл исходник. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5jig5E9hRMwYUowemNiZkdqWms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За это отвечает сам браузер, и хранит он это в памяти (кеше), либо в `temp` директории. Такую технологию дала нам: `File API` появившиеся в `HTML5`. Возможность просмотра данных о файле ещё до отправки его на сервер.

Вот хорошая [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) об этом. Большое количество примеров о том как выбирать файлы, как реализовать функцию `drag & drop`, и многое другое.

Answer (score 0):

[javascript форма сохранения файла на диск, в директорию определённую пользователем в свойствах броузера.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5jig5E9hRMwYUowemNiZkdqWms)
[image: javascript форма сохранения файла на диск, в директорию определённую пользователем в свойствах броузера.]